# How to tell what sign to keep when parameterizing intersection of two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-sections

I have this exercise: 
[The question as it is written in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93zs0.jpg). $z = x^{2}$ and $z = 4y^{2}$ intersect in two curves, one of which goes through the point $(2, -1, 4)$. Parameterize that curve.

My attempt: I parameterized using t=y. Got this result:$ x= \pm 2t$, $y =t$, $z= 4t^{2}$ 
Now, I know that x cannot have both a minus and a plus sign since they denote different curves. However I don't know how to think when deciding on the sign of $x$. I chose $x = -2t$ in the end because "it felt right" and it happened to be correct. But, I don't understand how I should think when deciding on this point.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Next time. please format your question using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You have a point that lies on the curve. Which choice of sign gets you to that point?

Comment: Ok, now I see. I set $x= \pm 2t$, $y = t$ , $z = 4t^{2}$ equal to $(2,-1,4)$ . We want $t$ in this case to be equal to $-1$, since we chose to parameterise $y$. If I had chosen $+2t$, then that would mean that $t=1$ which condradicts $y$. Therefore the only way for $x$ and $y$ to have the same $t$ is for $x= -2t$